# How do you change the value of a FormEditText or EditText in a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-volley

I tried to do it in onCreate, onStart, and even in onAttach(), but the alues just don't change. The values stays the same as what it is when the fragment wast first created. Here is how I do it

```
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.andreabaccega.widget.FormEditText;
import com.thesis.rentalpropertymanagement.R;
import com.thesis.rentalpropertymanagement.framework.RPMApiRequests;
import com.thesis.rentalpropertymanagement.framework.VolleyController;
import com.thesis.rentalpropertymanagement.interfaces.OnApiSuccessCalback;
import com.thesis.rentalpropertymanagement.models.RentalProperty;

public class ProfileFragment
    extends Fragment
    implements OnApiSuccessCalback {

    public static String ARGS_PROFILE = "profile";

    private RentalProperty property;

    private Button updateBtn;

    private FormEditText nameTxt;
    private FormEditText contactNoTxt;
    private FormEditText emailTxt;
    private FormEditText usernameTxt;
    private FormEditText passwordTxt;
    private FormEditText priceConditionsTxt;
    private FormEditText bathsTxt;
    private FormEditText bedroomsTxt;
    private FormEditText totalRoomsTxt;
    private FormEditText fullyFurnishedTxt;
    private FormEditText yearBuiltTxt;

    private View fragment;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(
        LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        fragment = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_property_profile,
            container, false);
        property = new RentalProperty((String) getArguments().get(ARGS_PROFILE));
        setUpViews(fragment);
        Log.d("ERNEST", "ProfileFragment : " + property.getJsonData().toString());
        return fragment;
    }

    public void setUpViews(View fragment) {
        updateBtn = (Button) fragment.findViewById(R.id.updateBtn);
        updateBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (dataAreValid()) {
                      VolleyController.instance.addToRequestQueue(RPMApiRequests
                        .updatePropertyInfo(getActivity(),
                            ProfileFragment.this, 1,
                            VolleyController.instance.getIpAddress(),
                            property));
                }

            }
        });
        nameTxt = (FormEditText) fragment.findViewById(R.id.name);
        nameTxt.setText(property.getLandlordName());

        contactNoTxt = (FormEditText) fragment.findViewById(R.id.contact_no);
        contactNoTxt.setText(property.getContactNo());

        emailTxt = (FormEditText) fragment.findViewById(R.id.email_ad);
        emailTxt.setText(property.getEmail());

        usernameTxt = (FormEditText) fragment.findViewById(R.id.username);
        usernameTxt.setText(property.getUsername());

        passwordTxt = (FormEditText) fragment.findViewById(R.id.password);
        passwordTxt.setText(property.getPassword());

        priceConditionsTxt = (FormEditText) fragment
            .findViewById(R.id.price_conditions);
        priceConditionsTxt.setText(property.getPriceConditions());

        bathsTxt = (FormEditText) fragment.findViewById(R.id.baths);
        bathsTxt.setText(String.valueOf(property.getBaths()));

        bedroomsTxt = (FormEditText) fragment.findViewById(R.id.bedrooms);
        bedroomsTxt.setText(String.valueOf(property.getBedrooms()));

        totalRoomsTxt = (FormEditText) fragment.findViewById(R.id.total_rooms);
        totalRoomsTxt.setText(String.valueOf(property.getTotalRooms()));

        fullyFurnishedTxt = (FormEditText) fragment
            .findViewById(R.id.fully_furnished);
        fullyFurnishedTxt.setText(getFullyFurnished());

        yearBuiltTxt = (FormEditText) fragment.findViewById(R.id.year_built);
        yearBuiltTxt.setText(property.getYearBuilt());
    }

    private String getFullyFurnished() {
        int fullyFurnished = property.isFullyFurnished();
        if (fullyFurnished == 1) {
            return "Y";
        } else {
            return "N";
        }
    }

    private int isFullyFurnished() {
        String fullyFurnished = fullyFurnishedTxt.getText().toString();
        if (fullyFurnished.toUpperCase().contains("Y")) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public boolean dataAreValid() {
        if (nameTxt.testValidity() && contactNoTxt.testValidity()
            && emailTxt.testValidity() && usernameTxt.testValidity()
            && passwordTxt.testValidity()
            && priceConditionsTxt.testValidity() && bathsTxt.testValidity()
            && bedroomsTxt.testValidity() && totalRoomsTxt.testValidity()
            && fullyFurnishedTxt.testValidity()
            && yearBuiltTxt.testValidity()) {
            property = new RentalProperty(nameTxt.getText().toString(),
                contactNoTxt.getText().toString(), emailTxt.getText()
                .toString(), usernameTxt.getText().toString(),
                passwordTxt.getText().toString(), priceConditionsTxt
                .getText().toString(), Integer.parseInt(bathsTxt
                .getText().toString()),
                Integer.parseInt(bedroomsTxt.getText().toString()),
                Integer.parseInt(totalRoomsTxt.getText().toString()),
                isFullyFurnished(), yearBuiltTxt.getText().toString());
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void OnApiSuccess(JSONObject response, int requestCode) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

Comment: do it in `onCreateView()`, depends on what you are trying to do though.

Comment: I've been doing that. It doesn't seem to change the values. The setUpViews method gets the views from the `fragment` by `findViewById` and then uses `setText` to set the data from my model

Comment: ....can you post the relevant segment of the code for the `Fragment`?

Comment: I'll post it. I just want to curse this fragment, it stays the same even after I uninstalled the application! Like WTF

Comment: Luckily in programming, things happen for a reason, so if you share some of the source that could be the cause of the problem, we'll figure it out :)

Comment: ....except when it's Volley. I never understood Volley. I hope someone will be able to help you out with that.

Answer (score 0):

I set value of Textview in onActivityCreated

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);


        inputSend = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.inputSend);
        inputSend.setText("xxxxxxx");

}
```